# Is there any way to run compute shaders from a Unity console application?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hlsl, compute-shader

As part of a job application, I've been asked to compile some Unity code outside Unity, as a standalone console application. I've done this.

Next, I've been asked to optimise the code using the GPU. I don't believe this is possible when compiling outside Unity, without resorting to a 3rd-party HLSL library. It doesn't appear to be possible to use ComputeShader, as there's no way to load the shader file in to the ComputeShader object. (Resources.Load is not allowed in a console application.)

Is my understanding correct here? Or is there a way to do it that I haven't found?

Comment: What platform are you targeting?

Comment: `I've been asked to compile some Unity code outside Unity, as a standalone console application` what code and ... why? ^^

Comment: I'm working in OSX but I think they want me to produce a Windows executable for review.

Comment: The code is just some test code that produces a load of objects, manipulates them, and deletes them. Optimising it in a compute shader is no problem, I just don't think it's possible to use compute shaders in a Unity console app

Comment: What do you mean by saying "Resources.Load is not allowed"? Is there a compilation error? Do you link the Unity DLLs?